# global $wpdb wordpress problems after upgrading php 5.3 to 5.5, not working when logged in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Can anyone confirm, that when logged into a wordpress website the global $wpdb doesnt work in own template scripts.

First i run into some problems after upgrading to php 5.5 (from 5.3)
The website was running, but when logging into the wordpress i got those messages
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) 
then after adding root in mysql

Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 after adding apache
i got no database selected. But only when i am logged in the wordpress website

Whats going wrong here, got it now working by bypassing global $wpdb but thats not the way i want it

Answer (score 0):

Its because ur template scripts using mysql.

When wordpress detect php 5.5 its uses mysqli extension.

**WordPress 3.9 now uses the MySQLi Improved extension for sites running PHP 5.5. Any plugins that made direct calls to mysql_* functions will experience some problems on these sites. For more information, see the notes on the core development blog.**

http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

Solution :

**You have to change mysql_query to $wpdb->query or $wpdb->get_results**

check code here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb